# How to Handle Routes for Module from NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular2-routing

I have an Angular module that I'm loading from an NPM module.  How do I load the routes from it?  Here is a snippet from my app.module.ts file:

```
import { HelloWorldModule } from 'hello-world-app-npm/hello-world-app.umd.js'; // The module loaded from NPM

const routes = [
{ path: 'hw', loadChildren: () => HelloWorldModule },
{ path: '', component: AppComponent },
]

@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HelloWorldModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
],
exports: [RouterModule],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is how I've define my hello world module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HelloWorldComponent } from './hello-world.component';

export const routes = [{ path: '', component: HelloWorldComponent }]

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [HelloWorldComponent],
    declarations: [
        HelloWorldComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ]
})
export class HelloWorldModule {
}
```

When I go to "/hw" I get an error in chrome saying

> Uncaught (in promise): RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

What am I doing wrong?  How do I fix this?

Comment: How can i reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could be because of two things.

1. `HelloWorldModule` should not be appear inside `AppModule` import.
2. `bootstrap: [HelloWorldComponent]` inside `HelloWorldModule` is unnecessary.